# Bootstrap 5 responsive radius (rounded)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap 5.3.1. I have already added responsive radius via Utility API, and can confirm that my CSS file includes classes like `.rounded-top-sm-4`, `.rounded-end-sm-4`, etc.

```
# utilities_custom.scss
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/variables-dark";
@import "bootstrap/maps";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/utilities";
    
$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities, (
    "rounded": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "rounded"),
      ( responsive: true ),
    ),
    "rounded-top": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "rounded-top"),
      ( responsive: true ),
    ),
    "rounded-bottom": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "rounded-bottom"),
      ( responsive: true ),
    ),
    "rounded-start": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "rounded-start"),
      ( responsive: true ),
    ),
    "rounded-end": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "rounded-end"),
      ( responsive: true ),
    ),
  )
);
```

Here's the my markup:

```
  <div class="card border-0 mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center g-0 fs-4">
      <div class="test col-md-4 rounded-4 rounded-end-md-0 rounded-bottom-sm-0">
        <div class="card-body p-5">
          <p class="card-text">...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Expected:

1. On medium screen, I want `.test` to have `radius-4` on top-left and bottom-left
2. On small screen, I want `.test` to have `radius-4` on top-left and top-right

Actual:

1. On medium screen, top-left has `radius-4`, the rest is radius 0.
2. On small screen, all corners have `radius-4`

What have I done wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to explicitly set the md screen radius:

```
<div class="col-md-4 rounded-top-4 rounded-start-md-4 rounded-end-md-0">
```